# calculate difference in minutes between dateTime values in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to calculate the difference between date time in minutes

```
xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]","2017-01-17T08:00:00")
xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]","2017-01-17T22:45:00")
```

I tried using

```
xquery version "0.9-ml"
fn:subtract-dateTimes-yielding-dayTimeDuration(
  xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]","2017-01-17T08:00:00"),
  xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]","2017-01-17T22:45:00")
)
```

**Output is**

```
-PT14H45M
```

I want the output in minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the functx library [**`functx:total-minutes-from-duration()`**](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_total-minutes-from-duration.html):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at
 "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";

functx:total-minutes-from-duration(
  xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]","2017-01-17T08:00:00")
  - xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]","2017-01-17T22:45:00")
)
```

Comment: The functx library is just doing a `div xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1M")` too. Great library, but perhaps a little overkill for such a simple task.. ;-)

Comment: yeah. I know - but It's a good library to know is available. Not every task is as simple. Plus, the docs fort he library are so good that its a nice way to see how things are done. A good way to expand knowledge - if you take the time to look at the underlying code for the functions. Maybe overkill for this one, but a good source for alot of other items. Plus, it is a good assumptions that the library is written well and efficient. If a function is not already ported to the ML fn namespace, then i would confidently take the functx ones.

Answer (score 4):

Substract the dates, and divide by dayTimeDuration for 1 minute:

```
let $date1 := xs:dateTime("2017-01-17T08:00:00")
let $date2 := xs:dateTime("2017-01-17T22:45:00")
return fn:abs(($date1 - $date2) div xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1M"))
```

HTH!

Comment: By the way, that date pattern matches xs:dateTime format, so you can just do `xs:dateTime("2017-01-17T08:00:00")`